# Swift bool data not passed to tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview that gets the data from an API. There is a ***isUnlocked*** variable that is also getting value from the API.
But besides the title and picture, the ***isUnlocked*** variable still has the default value set in the custom tableview class.

I pass the value in cellForRow function like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if tableView.tag == 1 {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CourseViewIdentifiers.courses.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! CourseViewTableViewCell
        c.isUnlocked = tableData[indexPath.row].unlocked
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        c.courseTitle.text = tableData[indexPath.row].title
        c.courseImage.loadImageFrom(urlString: tableData[indexPath.row].pic)
        cell = c
    }
    return cell
}
```

And this is the custom class for tableview cell:

```
public var isUnlocked: Bool = false

private lazy var backView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    return view
}()

public lazy var courseImage: WebImageloader = {
    let imv = WebImageloader()
    imv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imv
}()

public lazy var courseTitle: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.iransans(size: 18)
    label.textAlignment = .right
    return label
}()

private lazy var courseButton1: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    if !isUnlocked {
        button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "locked"), for: .normal)
        button.isEnabled = false
    }else{
        button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play"), for: .normal)
    }
    return button
}()

private lazy var courseButton2: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "download"), for: .normal)
    return button
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: CourseViewIdentifiers.courses.rawValue)
    print(isUnlocked,"***************")
    setupUI()
    contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
}

private func setupUI() {

    backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(backView)
    backView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    backView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    backView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    backView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    backView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

    courseImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backView.addSubview(courseImage)
    courseImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    courseImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    courseImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    courseImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    courseImage.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    courseImage.clipsToBounds = true

    courseButton1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backView.addSubview(courseButton1)
    courseButton1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    courseButton1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    courseButton1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    courseButton1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    courseButton1.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    courseButton1.clipsToBounds = true

    if isUnlocked {
        courseButton2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backView.addSubview(courseButton2)
        courseButton2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: courseButton1.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        courseButton2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        courseButton2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        courseButton2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        courseButton2.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        courseButton2.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    courseTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backView.addSubview(courseTitle)
    courseTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: courseImage.leftAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    courseTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: courseImage.topAnchor).isActive = true
    courseTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: courseButton1.rightAnchor, constant: 10)

}
```

The isUnlocked variable has the default False value no matter what I set it in the cellForRow function. Guys it's killing me please help.

Comment: Please update question with API response in json format.

Comment: @AyazRafai the problem is not with the api, the bool variable is stuck in false value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding this block of code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if DownloadManager.isDownloading(url: self.course_url!) {
            self.courseButton2.alpha = 0.5
            self.courseButton2.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

Just add this code to the cell, and your ok to go!

Comment: How does this answer the question, let alone solve it? Oh i see that it is the OP that has answered! What is the deal OP?

Answer (score 2):

I think your value is being set, but your UI is not being updated because it only gets set during initialization, where obviously the value of the `Bool` will always be the default value (false). So instead of calling `setUpUI()` in `init()`, call it after dequeue-ing.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if tableView.tag == 1 {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CourseViewIdentifiers.courses.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! CourseViewTableViewCell
        c.isUnlocked = tableData[indexPath.row].unlocked
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        c.courseTitle.text = tableData[indexPath.row].title
        c.courseImage.loadImageFrom(urlString: tableData[indexPath.row].pic)
        c.setUpUI()
        //print(c.isUnlocked)
        cell = c
    }
    return cell
}
```

Or atleast move the set up of `courseButton2` to another method and call that method.

Comment: I set the c.isUnlocked = true and I printed the value in custom cell class and it was still false. Wierd1

Comment: Where did you print it?

Comment: override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: CourseViewIdentifiers.courses.rawValue)
    print(isUnlocked,"***************")
    setupUI()
    contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
}

Comment: The issue is that you only setup the button in the init function. After you change the value of isUnlocked, it does nothing to the UI. So although you set a value and can read the value, you aren't doing anything with the value.

Comment: And also the ui is working, just this variable is not being set

Comment: During the `init`, the variable hasn't changed. Put a breakpoint where you setting the value and put a breakpoint where you are printing the value and check which one is called first. You will understand. :)

Comment: @Abizern the problem is the value is not being set, it is false the whole time

Comment: @PouyaKahfi Check the edit, i have commented out a line. Uncomment it and check the value being printed there.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri true value

Comment: Yes. Did you keep the breakpoints like i said and check? You will understand better if you do that. It's simply the code flow. It'll be a little confusing when you are new to programming. But practice and it'll become easier.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thanks, so how to set the value before the init?

Comment: You cannot. The cell is created only on `init`. You can however clear all the values to default using `prepareForReuse`.